# remove items from custom List

Tags: java, list

I have two custom List objects. I am trying to return records if Id matches in both list. I am doing a foreach loop and setting id to those that only has a match but in my webpage I am getting records that do not match in both list , like Id 1234 is in Student but not in teacher but still it is displaying.

```
List<Student> studentEnrolled = studentreport.getStudents();
List<Teacher> teachersFacu = teacherreport.getTeachers();

for(Teacher tcReport: teachersFacu){
    for(Student stu: studentEnrolled){

        if(tcReport.getId().equals(stu.getId())){ // setting new id if there is only a match
            String ids= stu.getId();
            stu.setId(ids);

        }
    }
}

return studentEnrolled; // this is returning id even if there is no match
```

Comment: What are setId and getId methods doing. Those 2 lines inside the IF seem useless.

Comment: You are getting student ID and setting it back to student ID ? why ? You are basically doing nothing; you are looping and if student and teacher IDs match, you take out student ID and assign it back to student (which is useless) .

Comment: Gosh! What a weird piece of codes. The returned object stays unchanged because it was useless as @MikeB said.

Comment: @MikeB I am trying to return records that have match in both list , I am setting matched Ids in If condition so webpage will display only those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to filter and return only matches. Something like:

```
List<Student> studentEnrolled = studentreport.getStudents();
List<Teacher> teachersFacu = teacherreport.getTeachers();

Set<String> teachersIds = teachersFacu.stream().map(Teacher::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());

return studentEnrolled.stream()
                      .filter(stud -> teachersIds.contains(stud.getId()))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you want to stick with the classic for loop

```
List<Student> studentEnrolled = studentreport.getStudents();
List<Teacher> teachersFacu = teacherreport.getTeachers();

List<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(Student stu: studentEnrolled){    
   if(teachersListContainsSameId(stu.getId(), teachersFacu)){ 
        result.add(stu);
   }
}    
return result;
```

where `teachersListContainsSameId` is a helper method:

```
boolean teachersListContainsSameId(String id, List<Teacher> list){
     for(Teacher techer: list){
        if(teacher.getId().equals(id)){
            return true;
        }
     }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will try these and will update you shortly.

Comment: May be you shoud also consider @aran´s answer. It does the same but is some how much more readable/ compact than mine.

Comment: @Eritrean no you! I like yours more : )

Comment: @Eritrean worked perfect- appreciated for your great help.

Comment: @user13079741 Glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Integer> teachersSet = new HashSet<>();
List<Student> goodStudentList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Teacher tcReport: teacherreport.getTeachers())
    teachersSet.add(tcReport.getId());

for(Student stu: studentreport.getStudents())
    if (teachersSet.contains(stu.getId())
        goodStudentList.add(stu);

return goodStudentList;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display same id's just remove them with the remove() method.
If you get a match in your if clause then say

```
teachersFacu.remove(tcReport);
studentEnrolled.remove(stu);
```

So you removed the matching teacher an student from your list.

Comment: I am trying to remove unmatched Ids. How can I do this

Comment: Change your if clause to if( ! teacherId.equals(studentId)) so you have an if not statement and within this just remove like above.